# What is wrong with my logistic regression implementation?

Tags: machine-learning, python

Recently, I implemented the LR algorithm in Python. The main part of the code is as following(I didn't use mini batch in my code. Instead, I use the whole batch to compute gradients every time):

```
class Logistic():
def __init__(self):
    self.w = None
    self.lr = 10.
    pass
def train(self, xs, ys):
    m, n = xs.shape
    ones = np.ones([m, 1])
    xs = np.hstack([xs, ones])
    ys = np.expand_dims(ys, -1)
    self.w = np.ones([n+1, 1], dtype=np.float64) * 1.0
    epochs = 100
    for epoch in xrange(epochs):
        y_ = self.sigmoid(-np.dot(xs, self.w))
        # loss = -1.0/m * np.sum(ys * np.log(y_) + (1 - ys) * np.log(1 - y_))
        tmp1 = np.sum(np.log(y_[np.where(ys==1)]))
        tmp2 = np.sum(np.log(1 - y_[np.where(ys==0)]))
        loss = - (tmp1 + tmp2) / m
        print("epoch: %d, loss: %f" % (epoch, loss))
        print("y_: %f, %f" % (np.min(y_), np.max(y_)))
        grad =  np.sum((y_ - ys) * xs, axis=0) / m
        self.w -= self.lr * np.expand_dims(grad, -1)
        print("grad: %f, %f" % (np.min(grad), np.max(grad)))
        print("w: %f, %f" % (np.min(self.w), np.max(self.w)))
        print ""
```

The dataset I used is MNIST. I marked all digits 0 as class 0, and all other digits as class 1. Then I get this binary classification problem. I test my algorithm with many different learning rate, from 1e-6 to 10, and it turns out all of them produces good results(about 98% accuracy on test set). As far as I know, if the learning rate is to big, LR will not converge. But here although I used very big learning rate, the algorithm still converge to about 98% accuracy. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Since you're already printing these things out: are your weights and loss function actually converging?

Answer (score 1):

What is the ratio between 0's and the other numbers? If the ratio is too low, let's say 2%, if you classify everything as not 0 you will have high accuracy.

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS**

Imagine there are 98 non zeroes and 2 zeroes, you don't need any classifier to have a 98% of accuracy...

Accuracy is not the best metric for unbalanced data-sets, let's try precision and recall and take a look to the confusion matrix

Comment: About 10% 0's and 90% other digits.

Comment: As I figured out, you have a very unbalanced data-set... Try to get rid off the 90% of the other digits, train again the algorithm, and let's see what happens...

Comment: Is the ratio the same in the training test than in the test set?

Comment: Yes, It's the same.

Comment: I didn't take a look to your implementation, but the first steps should be balancing the data-set and using other metrics.

Comment: I balanced my dataset(class 0 and class 1 now both consists of 50% of the dataset). It still gets 95% accuracy no matter how big learning rate I set...

Comment: Should you change the sign of tmp1 and remove the "-" in the cost?

Comment: Also check if you are really taking the average of the cost... I mean, something like np.sum(tmp1+tmp2)/m

Comment: I now think that the reason may be that I didn't include L1 or L2 regularization in the loss function. So when I used very big learning rate, the weights produced by the algorithm became very big(I checked this by printing weights out). But the prediction it produced is still correct.